# Merge two datatables while combining two columns in r

Tags: r, merge, datatable

I am trying to merge to datatables while combining the values of two columns.

**Example:**

Datatable X:

[image]

Datatable Y1:

[image]

So, when I merge X with Y1 by ID and Brand and keeping all values of X. I get datatable Z:

[image]

However, after this, I got datatable Y2:

[image]

An I would like to get this datatable when I merge it with Z:

[image]

Hopefully, that was clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Posting data as images really makes me cry. Please take a look at [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. First, vertically combine Y1..YN like this:

```
Yall = rbindlist(list(Y1,Y2,...,YN))
```

Then merge X with Yall.